# Fast processing of file & allocating a new object from file contents

Tags: c#, file, object

```
MapObject newMapObject = new MapObject();
        newMapObject.ID = Convert.ToInt16(Util.Between(Line, "<ID>", "</ID>"));
        newMapObject.Description = Util.Between(Line, "<Desc>", "</Desc>");
        newMapObject.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Util.Between(Line, "<Image>", "</Image>"));
```

My program reads a file, saves every line of the file in a prelocated string array, then handles the line in order to create a new object.
Isn't there a faster & cleaner way of achieving this? Using string seems a bit slow and noobish to me.

Comment: It looks like you are dealing with an xml file, have you considered using an xml serializer to deserialize your file to a collection of MapObjects? You might want to show us what kind of data structure you are dealing with in your file.

Comment: No , the files are plain text , i'm just using tags to get the data out of each line using a Between string function.

Comment: XML is plain text.  Do you have control of the format of the files?  ML serialization would be much cleaner and probably more efficient

Comment: Decided to use Json.NET ,much faster and cleaner.